# Migrated our Wordpress website to HTTPS, now FontAwesom Icons show up as Boxes?

Tags: wordpress, https, font-awesome

We just migrated our website, which is powered by Wordpress, to HTTPS.

Since doing that, our FontAwesome Icons are showing up as boxes or not at all (depends on which browser you use).

We are somewhat stumped on what could be causing this.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

[Our website is here](https://www.tricentis.com).

Comment: What are the files permissions? (/wp-content/themes/tricentis/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff)

Comment: Thank you, I will check. But if it worked before HTTPS should it not also work after HTTPS? All we did was install a certificate on the server and adjust Wordpress settings.

Comment: And about ublock/adblock?

Comment: Permissions on the file are -rw-r--r-- should translate to 644 i think

Comment: Try 775 for the test

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a caching issue? I'm seeing icons on the site (but I also have FA installed locally)

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone else having this issue, we ended up solving it.

We use MaxCDN as our CDN solution. After migrating to HTTPS we had to add CORS Headers. So in the MaxCDN backend, for the respective pull zone we had to enable: Allow Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

Once we did that the Font Awesome icons started working again.